# Div with a transparent cut out circle

Tags: css, css-shapes

Can I make a rectagle `div` with a half cut out circle using CSS? The half circle should be transparent and let the background show through.

desired CSS shape :

[image: square div with a transparent cut out half circle]

*HTML :*

```
<div></div>
```

*CSS :*

```
div{
    background : #448CCB;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
```

Comment: do you need to see through the white half circle? meaning should it show a background image, gradient...?

Comment: @web-tiki Do you think that's even possible?

Comment: yes it is with box shadows otherwise answers here should solve the issue

Comment: It is just one shape. the half circle part is a space.

Comment: this is solution with box-shadow as @web-tiki suggested http://jsfiddle.net/a7dcP/1/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order to have the white cut out circle transparent and let the background show through it, you can use `box-shadows` on a pseudo element to minimize markup.

In the following demo, the blue color of the shape is set with the box shadow and not the `background-color` property.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/yefw4/)**

output:

[image: Div with cut out half-circle]

This can also be responsive: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/yefw4/1/)

*HTML:*

```
<div></div>
```

*CSS:*

```
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 300px 0px 300px #448CCB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it okey ?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4x7jk/)

```
div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#03b0d5;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div:after{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:#fff;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    top:-50px;
    left:0;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I need the half circle part to be transparent/nothing. I just want the blue part to be the shape area

Comment: Yes , what is the different ? Its half circle :) @AeonWallace

Comment: @ShibinRagh the problem is that when you set background of div to transparent, you will not see half circle, but square.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sollution

HTML:

```
<div id="shape"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#shape {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    background:#448ccb;
    position:relative;
}

#shape:before {
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    background:#fff;
    left:0; top:-50%;
    border-radius:50%;
}
```

Link in jsfiddler: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a7dcP/)

Solition with box-shadow:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="shape"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap {
    background:#ccc;
    padding:20px;
}
#shape {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;    
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#shape:before {
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0; top:-50%;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow:0 0px 0 250px #448ccb
}
```

Link in jsfiddler: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a7dcP/2/)

Answer (score -3):

If you don't mind that the "eaten" bit is white and not transparent, yes:

http://jsfiddle.net/tWbx5/2/

[image]

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #448CCB;
}

div:before {
    content:" ";
    background:white;
    display: block;
    width:250px;
    height: 125px;
    border-radius: 0 0 125px 125px;
}
```