# How can I create a concave bottom border in CSS?

Tags: css, css-shapes

Content needs to be able to scroll behind it in the concave area and not be obscured. Specifically, I'm trying to create this:

[image: Concave bottom border div example]

Comment: Can you use PNG image for that?

Comment: I'm thinking an SVG image plus border-image might be the only way to go. I was hoping for a completely code-based solution.

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755864/div-with-a-transparent-cut-out-circle/24756255#24756255

Comment: I'd prefer a non-JS solution but as a last resort I may have to fall back on it.

Comment: Well, you could use SVG and change its color with JS...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a transparent background, you can use box-shadows :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ftw7d5ap/)**

**Explanation :**

The point of this technique is to use a pseudo element with box-shadows and a transparent backcground to see through it. The pseudo element is abolutely positioned and has a much larger width than the container in order to (with the help of border radius) give a smooth inset curve to the bottom of the div.

To make it simple : **The background of the div is the box-shadow of the pseudo element.**

The z-index values allow the content of the div to be dispayed over the shadow.

****** EDIT *************************

With content scolling behind the shape, you can see this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ftw7d5ap/4/)**

---

```css
html,body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
div {
    background:none;
    height:50%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1;
}
div:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:-600%;
    width:1300%;
    padding-bottom:1300%;
    top:80%;
    background:none;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 9999px teal;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div>content</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic! This seems to be the cleanest solution.

Comment: I like that solution, but it has to be pointed out that there are limitations regarding content 'inside the shape' (which is, to be honest, above the shape). There is no way to clip content inside the shape to the concave bottom line as well; it will simply overflow then.

Comment: @PeterSorowka I don't see what you mean exactly could explain please?

Comment: @web-tiki I mean what happens if you put more content inside the shape. (http://jsfiddle.net/ftw7d5ap/6/) This will not clip to the curve. But I see, this may not be an requirement.

Comment: @PeterSorowka that is because the shape has a specified height, if you remove it, the content will expand it as a normal element : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ftw7d5ap/8/

Comment: @web-tiki I see - not bad!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a way you could do this with a border, but you could try using `::before` in CSS3 combined with `border-radius` as shown in this demo.

```css
#header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 80px;
    background: #f00;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
#header::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    bottom: -22px;
    height: 30px;    
    left: -50px;
    right: -50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
#content {
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    width: 460px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: when i add multiple `Test<br />` in the div, the content doesn't seem to scroll, which is think is part of OP's request. or is just my browser that isn't scrolling, i'm in win8 chrome. doesn't seem to work in IE or FF. points for a spot on visual solution though.

Comment: @Dpeif Fair enough, I have altered my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I just did the same thing in jsFiddle. Only solution I know. It can't scroll because he fixed the height for the example. Feel free to remove it and test.

Comment: I've made some tweaks based on your fiddle, which gets the shape looking right. However, if I were to put content behind the div, it would be obscured by the white ::before element as it scrolled behind. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/nbt4Le0n/

Comment: Not quite, needs to have the text content scroll behind the shape.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at using the CSS clipping / masking techniques for your purpose.

Specifically, you can specify the boundaries you want to achieve by some SVG definitions:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <mask id="masking">
      <!-- white area means: visible -->
      <rect width="300" height="300" fill="white"/>

      <!-- black area means: hidden -->
      <ellipse rx="150" ry="10" cx="150" cy="300" fill="black" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

And refer to this mask within CSS using:

```
#your-div {

    mask: url('#masking');
}
```

I have created a little example that demonstrates this in the following fiddle. This still has to be tweaked a bit in order to be more flexible when it comes to different dimensions, but it should light you the way: http://jsfiddle.net/m8fo5zbk/

UPDATE: Following fiddle also shows scrolling behavior http://jsfiddle.net/m8fo5zbk/2/ - did I understand correctly what you intended?

2nd UPDATE: Now understood that content should be placed *inside* of the div, reflected in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m8fo5zbk/3/

Comment: Very close. I'm trying to put content inside the shape. My best attempt was to create another div above the curve, which gives the same visual effect, albeit with more markup: http://jsfiddle.net/z3x86k0r/

Answer (score 0):

I tested a way to achieve that using `border-top` of a pseudo element (here, :after) : http://jsfiddle.net/z6eqvnxw/

```
.test {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;

}
.test:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    border-top: blue 10px solid;
    bottom: -23px;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 40%;
}
```

**That's not perfect, the render isn't great.**

Is using Javascript / Canvas an option ? Or only CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you require, is this what you require?

[Quick Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ot3hxtvz/)

html

```
 <div class="Fixed1"></div>
 <div class="scroll1">
 <p>DEMO CONTENT</p>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.Fixed1 {
    color: #666;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #06C;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top:40px;
}
.scroll1 {
    color: #333;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 720px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left:50px;
    margin-top:110px;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

Comment: The scrolling behind the div is working nicely here, but I'm not seeing a curve at the bottom of the blue area.