# How to create div with curve in css and html5?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am newbie in css world and I am trying to make responsive design like this using bootstrap,css and html5.

[image]

but ended up like this.
[image]

how to create same curve in div displaying in image 1?
Note : Red color in second image is for better explanation.I have to apply white color anyway

Comment: If it were me, I would use an image that was attached to the `:after` and  `:before` or do something like http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ftw7d5ap/ (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25915415/3739498)

Answer (score 1):

You should use percentage to define the `border-radius`, in this way the curve will look like the one you want.

```
border-radius: 100%
```

http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/XKvkJX?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

To get curved edges use `border-radius`, the background can be achieved with `linear-gradient`

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ojhcbepz/

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
div.outer {
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,blue 50%,red 0px);
  padding: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.inner {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

well a simple solution maybe... use a small red dot image and repeat it in outer div and inner div has border-radius: 50%

```
<div style="background-image: red url("http://i.imgur.com/dXis68u.png") repeat;"> 

    <div style="background-color: white; border-radius: 50%; text-align:center;" >
         ABCDEFGH
    </div>
</div>
```

(You can add two

's of height as you want to get those top and bottom borders)